# Binding change not detected within List NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm building a picker component and am passing a Binding two layers deep. The issue is that I need to detect it's `.onChange` on the `PickerListView`, however, it never gets triggered.

```
import SwiftUI

public struct SectionItems<T: Hashable>: Hashable {
    let header: String
    public var items: [T]
    
    public init(header: String, items: [T]) {
        self.header = header
        self.items = items
    }
}

struct PickerListView<T: Hashable>: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @Binding var selected: T
    @Binding var sections: [SectionItems<T>]
    
    init(selected: Binding<T>, sections: Binding<[SectionItems<T>]>) {
        self._selected = selected
        self._sections = sections
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(sections, id: \.self) { section in
                Section(section.header) {
                    
                    ForEach(section.items, id: \.self) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                            selected = item
                            dismiss()
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Text(String(describing: item))
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                if selected == item {
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: sections) { _ in
            print("PickerListView: \(sections.count)") // Doesn't run
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

public struct PickerView<T: Hashable>: View {
    @Binding var selected: T
    @Binding var sections: [SectionItems<T>]

    public var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                String(describing: selected),
                destination: PickerListView(
                    selected: $selected,
                    sections: $sections
                )
            )
        }
        .onChange(of: sections) { _ in
            print("PickerView: \(sections.count)") // Runs
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selected = "33"
    @State private var sections = [
        SectionItems(header: "Itemr", items: [
            "33",
            "73",
            "38"
        ])
    ]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PickerView(selected: $selected, sections: $sections)
            
            Button("Add Value", action: {
                sections[0].items.append("\(Int.random(in: 1...100))")
            })
        }
        .onChange(of: sections) { _ in
            print("ContentView: \(sections.count)") // Runs
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deep bindings work unreliable, especially in NavigationView, they just loose source. Consider using ObservableObject instead, at least for internal purpose.

Comment: `sections` is never mutated in your `PickerListView` and by the time you press your button in `ContentView` to add a new value `PickerListView` is not shown, is it?

Comment: @burnsi It is not shown when a new item is added.

Comment: So when `PickerListView` is not shown while updating `sections`, `onChange(of` in your `PickerListView` will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different approach, instead of passing multiple items across many `View`s you can combine all the variables in a single `ObservableObject`

Then you can use `didSet` to make any changes you would make with `onChange`

```
///Keeps all the code needed for several views in one spot
class SectionViewModel<T: Hashable>: ObservableObject{
    @Published var selected : T
    @Published var sections : [SectionItems<T>]{
        didSet{
            //Use didSet instead of onChange
            print("\(type(of: self)) :: \(#function) :: \(sections.count)")
            print("\(type(of: self)) :: \(#function) :: section[0]items count: \(sections[0].items.count)")
        }
    }
    init(selected : T, sections : [SectionItems<T>]){
        self.selected = selected
        self.sections = sections
    }
}
```

Your `View`s would look something like

```
struct PickerListView<T: Hashable>: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: SectionViewModel<T>
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(vm.sections, id: \.self) { section in
                Section(section.header) {
                    ForEach(section.items, id: \.self) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                            vm.selected = item
                            dismiss()
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Text(String(describing: item))
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                if vm.selected == item {
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Use didset for any changes
        //        .onChange(of: vm.sections) { _ in
        //            print("PickerListView: \(vm.sections.count)") // Doesn't run
        //        }
    }
}

public struct PickerView<T: Hashable>: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: SectionViewModel<T>
    public var body: some View {
        //Navigation View should be at the top
        //NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(
            String(describing: vm.selected),
            destination: PickerListView<T>(vm: vm)
        )
        // }
        //Use did set for any actions
        //            .onChange(of: vm.sections) { _ in
        //                print("PickerView: \(vm.sections.count)") // Runs
        //                print("PickerView section[0]items count: \(vm.sections[0].items.count)") // Runs
        
        //       }
    }
}

struct SampleDeepView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: SectionViewModel = .init(selected: "33", sections: [
        SectionItems(header: "Itemr", items: [
            "33",
            "73",
            "38"
        ])
    ])
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                PickerView(vm: vm)
                //Adding an item not a section
                Button("Add Value", action: {
                    vm.sections[0].items.append("\(Int.random(in: 1...100))")
                })
                //Adding a section
                Button("Add Section", action: {
                    vm.sections.append(
                        SectionItems(header: "Itemr", items: [
                            "33",
                            "73",
                            "38"
                        ])
                    )
                })
            }
        }
        //Use didset for any actions
        //        .onChange(of: vm.sections) { _ in
        //            print("ContentView section[0]items count: \(vm.sections[0].items.count)") // Runs
        //        }
    }
}
```